# Python Equivalent to Ruby 'is_a?'

Tags: python, ruby

I'm wondering is there a Python Equivalent to Ruby's 'is_a?' method?

```
> "".is_a? String
=> true
```

[Info:](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Object.html#method-i-is_a-3F)

```
is_a?(class) → true or false
```

> Returns true if class is the class of obj, or if class is one of the
>   superclasses of obj or modules included in obj.

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends on exactly what part you want.

If you want to know whether `foo` is an instance of class `C` or [any of its subclasses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance), then:

```
isinstance(foo, C)
```

If you want to know whether `foo` is an instance of `C` and only `C`, then:

```
type(foo) == C
```

Broadly speaking, frequent use of things like `isinstance(...)` or `type(...)` is a code smell because it means duck typing is broken, and Python relies heavily on that sort of contract. See, e.g., **[isinstance considered harmful](http://www.canonical.org/%7Ekragen/isinstance/)**.

Comment: Thanks for the _isinstance considered harmful link_, that adds some really nice/important context...

Answer (score 4):

I've never used Ruby, but that functionality looks a lot like what [`isinstance`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#isinstance) does:

```
>>> a = "string"
>>> isinstance(a, str)
True
>>>
```

Also, in case you don't know, here is a reference on [`str`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#str).

Answer (score 2):

There is an `isinstance(a,b)` function to check whether `a` is of type `b`.